# MUI v5 : How to pass css classes to components using className prop? Also I want to use theme in those classes?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

MUI v5 : How to pass css classes to components using className prop? Also I want to use theme in those classes?  I was trying to do it using styled in MUIv5, but if am not wrong we can target certain classes using styled but cannot pass those classes to the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way for achieving this is to define the css class at a `sx` property of a parent component, like in the following example:

```
function Child({ message, className }) {
  return <Typography className={className}>{message}</Typography>;
}

function Parent() {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        '.childClass': {
          color: 'primary.main'
        }
      }}
    >
      <Child message="Child with no css class defined" />

      <Child className="childClass" message="Child with css class defined" />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

In this example, `'primary.main'` resolves to `theme.pallete.primary.main`, as mentioned [here](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#palette).

Answer (score 1):

You need to first import that css file in that component.Then you can pass it like this

```
<div className={name of your class that you imported}>
```

Comment: You don't need to import it. Importing is not related to React - it is related to an eventual bundler - like Webpack - which then can generate the bundle accordingly. For React a CSS class is nothing but a string.

Comment: I am not talking about importing css class name. But one must tell react where you are getting the className from.That's why importing the css file is important in that component.

Comment: name of your class that you imported => but I want to use theme in my css and it cannot be done using .css file. Can you tell me a way to create these classes without using .css file so that I can use mui theme and then use those classes in the className prop?